# Import range after the last blank row

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need help creating Dash Board. Sheet1 is a live Form response Sheet with all the data. Sheet2, Sheet3, and Sheet4 all have pivot tables pointing to data in Sheet1. I want to create a Dashboard in Sheet5 with data from the pivot tables in Sheet2,3 and 4 one after the other. The problem I am facing is if more rows are added to Pivot in Sheet2, the data disappears in Sheet5. I want to list all pivot data in all sheets that will recognise the last blank row and place the pivot data one after the other.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output